# PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver in unit test does not parse sort direction

Tags: junit, spring-boot

I have the controller and unit test shown below.  The controller returns a sorted list.  In the unit test, the sort field is passed correctly; however, the sort direction is not being parsed:

[image]

I am following these examples:

[Isolated Controller Test can't instantiate Pageable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22181848/188474)

[4. Paging and Sorting](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/paging-chapter.html)

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping("/telemetry")
public Page<TelemetryMessage> List(Pageable pageable) {
    return telemetryMessageRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(new TelemetryController(telemetryMessageRepository))
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
            .setViewResolvers(new ViewResolver() {
                @Override
                public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
                    return new MappingJackson2JsonView();
                }
            })
            .build();
    // etc.
}

@Test
public void testListReturnsDefault20() throws Exception {

    Iterable<TelemetryMessage> expected = telemetryMessageRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 20, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(expected);

    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/telemetry")
            .param("sort", "id")
            .param("id.dir", "desc")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    String actual = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `comma` to separate the `Property` and the `Direction`, like following:

```
MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/telemetry")
            .param("sort", "id,desc")
            //.param("id.dir", "desc")
```