# How to test REST controller which use Pageable objec

Tags: java, testing, junit, spring-data, mockito

I have a REST controller like above

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "client", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public Page<ClientWithAddress> getAllClientsWithAddres(Pageable pageable){
    return clientService.getAllClients(pageable);
}
```

When i try to run JUnit for it I got a NullPointerException on line with ***mockMvc.perform(get("/client")***

```
 @Test
public void Should_ReturnAllClients() throws Exception {
    when(clientService.getAllClients(pageable)).thenReturn((page));
    mockMvc.perform(get("/client"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

Its probably, because i dont how o transfer Pageable object in test whean i call scope ***"/client"*** .

There is the stack

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
at pl.xxxx.controller.ClientControllerUnitTest.Should_ReturnAllClients(ClientControllerUnitTest.java:133)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.getArgumentResolver(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:135)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.supportsParameter(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
... 38 more
```

Comment: This seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174665/isolated-controller-test-cant-instantiate-pageable

Answer (score 3):

the following one works for me,

```
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(myController)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
            .build();

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
    .get()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are instantiating your pageable object in your class here:

```
@Test
public void Should_ReturnAllClients() throws Exception {
    when(clientService.getAllClients(pageable)).thenReturn((page));
    mockMvc.perform(get("/client"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

But I certainly doubt it will be the same pageable object created by the call to the controller. What you probably want to do is use a matcher in your stubbing instead:

```
when(clientService.getAllClients(Matchers.any(Pageable.class)).thenReturn((page));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and @WebMvcTest(YourControllerUnderTest.class) then also add @EnableSpringDataWebSupport