# Testing rest controller with PageableDefault

Tags: spring, rest, mockmvc

Im trying to test a rest service that has *@getmapping* one param and PageableDefault

```
   @GetMapping(path = "/api/{serial}/gender")
    public ResponseEntity<?> task(
        @PathVariable(value = "serial") String Serial,
        @PageableDefault(size = 5, value = 0) Pageable pageable) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(page);
}
```

The test suite its with mockmvc

```
@Test
public void testTask() throws Exception {
 String url ="/api/123456789/gender";
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url))
           .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();
}
```

I got the following error , im unable to inject Pageable cause its a interface
how can i mock the @pageable default ?

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Add @EnableSpringDataWebSupport annotation to your test. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057262/failed-to-instantiate-pageable-bean

Comment: Add @EnableSpringDataWebSupport annotation to your test class. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057262/failed-to-instantiate-pageable-bean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guilhermo,

Try this piece of code :

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
   .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
   .setViewResolvers(new ViewResolver() {
       @Override
       public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
          return new MappingJackson2JsonView();
      }
   })
   .build();
```

See this post for further information: [Isolated Controller Test can't instantiate Pageable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174665/isolated-controller-test-cant-instantiate-pageable)

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Pageable in test can cause some trouble especially when you using some additional tools like swagger or local data base only for tasting like H2.

First of all we must add controller which we want to test:

```
@Autowired
private TestingController testingController;
```

Simple test for controller without Pagable can look like this:

```
    given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).log().all().
        standaloneSetup(testingController).
        body(new RequestObjectExample()).
        when().
        post("/someUrl?page=0&size=10,asc").
        then().statusCode(200);
```

and simple test for controller with Pagable can look like this:

```
    StandaloneMockMvcBuilder standaloneMockMvcBuilder = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(testingController)
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver);

    given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).log().all().
        standaloneSetup(standaloneMockMvcBuilder).
        body(new RequestObjectExample()).
        when().
        post("/someUrl?page=0&size=10,asc").
        then().statusCode(200);
```

P.S. to get pageableArgumentResolver just import PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver and inject it in class:

```
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;

@Inject
    private PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableArgumentResolver;
```