# RestAssuredMvc cannot resolve Pageable

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, rest-assured

I'm using RestAssured in my tests, in which I also mock the service layers. In order to do so, I had to change my test setup from `webAppContextSetup` to `standAloneSetup`. This way, I'm able to create an instance of my controller and `@InjectMock` the mocked services into it.

**Code:**

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(controller); -> Brakes test
    RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext); -> Works fine
}
```

The test is the following:

```
Mockito.when(findService.findUnreadNotificationItems(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn(new PageImpl<>(List.of(generateDummyNotificationItemWithId())) {
                });

        final String response = given()
                .queryParam("page", "0")
                .queryParam("size", "10")
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .log().all()
                .when()
                .get("/notification/{groupName}/{userName}", "subacquiring_viewers", "John.Doe")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .extract().asString();
```

And the endpoint:

```
public Page<NotificationItemResponse> findUnreadNotifications(@PageableDefault(size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) final Pageable pageable,
            @PathVariable final String groupName, @PathVariable final String userName)
```

When I use the `standAloneSetup` I get the error:

```
No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
```

I've seen a very similar question with good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174665/isolated-controller-test-cant-instantiate-pageable), but RestAssuredMvc does not have any resolvers, or at least I found nothing on it searching the web. **Can anyone help me resolve Pageables using RestAssuredMvc's standAloneSetup?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that standaloneSetup has an overload that takes an MockMvcBuilder as argument. I could accomplish the customArgumentResolver with the following:

```
@BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
                .setControllerAdvice(new NotificationItemControllerAdvice()));
    }
```